# Access the database via PHP from outside the server

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql, php

I have a VPS running `apache` and `mysql` servers.
Basically, I am updating my database from the website which is also hosted on the same server, that's why when I am connecting to the database via the `PHP` files I am using `127.0.0.1` to make the connection and I can connect and insert rows successfully.

However, recently, I tried to connect and insert rows to my database via a `php` script that is outside the server and residing on a different VPS, and I got the following error.
`( ! ) Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp64\www\test.php on line 13`

I want my `mySql` server to accept connections from outside the localhost also.

Comment: Check the credentials that you use from the "outside" host. The error says `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)` that means that you do not use a password (that may be the problem) and you are not on the localhost anymore. Also check if the user has the correct permissions (form your "outside" host, write permissions on the correct tables, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant the user all required privileges using the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pass'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
```

`%` means all hosts, so that specified user can access the database from any ip-address. You can specify your own ip-address if you have your own.

Don't forget to add an exception to the firewall on your VPS, if you have one. 
If you use `ufw` then you can execute the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp
sudo service ufw restart
```

Then finally don't forget to edit `my.cnf` on your system which is place in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` if you use Ubuntu. 
open the file using your favorite text editor: 
for example nano: `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
then add following:

```
[mysqld] 
bind-address= your-server-ip-address
#skip-networking
```

Save the file and exit. 
Don't forget then to run 
`sudo systemctl restart mysql`

You can test your work using this php script

```php
<?php
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'db_user';
$dbpass = 'db_pass';
$dbhost = 'your-server-ip-address';

try {
   $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, 
   $dbpass);

 $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   echo "Connected successfully"; 
 }
catch(PDOException $e)
   {
     echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
```